# How to ACCEPT multicast connection with iptables's rule?

Tags: iptables, firewall, udp, multicast

I obtain this row with iptables logging option:

> IN= OUT=eno49 SRC=192.168.0.72 DST=224.1.0.2 LEN=196 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=5 ID=53310 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=9100 DPT=8100 this packet is DROPPED

I think this is a multicast connection.

Which is the rule that accept this packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify you want to accept multicast. For example, based on your logs :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eno49 -p udp --dport 8100 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: '--sport 9100' is necessary?

Comment: Nothing is necessary but `-m pkttype --pkt-type multicast`, I just wanted to give an accurate example.